# Android OnPrepareOptionsMenu with ActionBar on Overflow Click

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-menu

I would like to have `onPrepareOptionsMenu` called every time a user clicks the overflow menu button (3 dots). From what I understand, on HC+ devices the menu is considered to always be showing, so `onPrepareOptionsMenu` will only be called the first time, or after `invalidateMenuOptions` is called. My question is, how do I call `invalidateMenuOptions` on an overflow button click? This is in a `Fragment` that is in an `ActionBarCompat ActionBarActivity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply call invalidateOptionsMenu from a Fragment like this:

```
getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

But I am not sure what will happen if you call that when the overflow button is clicked. It is very possible that this will mess with the behavior of the ActionBar and it might not be worth your time to make this work.

Also you have to consider that not all devices actually display the overflow menu in that way. For example all devices with a menu button - like pretty much all devices from Samsung and many older ones - do not display the overflow menu button at all. So you should probably reconsider and try to solve your problem some other way.

Comment: The second part of your answer answers most of what I was asking. Perhaps I wasn't being clear with my question, but it was more of **where** do I call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` (how can I tell when the overflow button was clicked)?

Comment: I'm not so sure if it is that easy, and as I already mentioned, making this work on a lot of devices may be difficult too. For devices with a menu button I guess you could override onKeyDown but I'm not sure if that would work. But it would most certainly not work for devices which display an overflow menu in the actionbar. I think the best possible solution for this would be to search for an alternative which does not involve reacting to the user pressing the menu button or the overflow menu button.

Comment: Capturing the menu button works in onKeyDown. The key code for the menu button is KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU.

Comment: I was considering that. Does that catch the overflow button? I didn't get a chance to test it. If it does I'll revisit it, but in the meantime I just changed my logic to not need this.

Comment: Most likely not. If I get a chance to test it, I will let you know. Since you already changed your logic to not need this I would recommend you stick with it.